# How to load csv file to Hive table with \n symbols inside text columns

Tags: csv, import, load, hive

I'm trying to load CSV file to Hive table and my file contains '\n'  - carriage return symbols inside some text columns.

Is there an easy way to import this to Hive?
I know I can write custom format for this, but possibly there is easier way?

UPDATED

sample data (CSV) 2 lines:

"1","title","some text","more detailed text \n with some carriage returns\n\n\n"
"2","title2","some text2","more detailed text2222 \n with some carriage returns\n\n\n"

schema:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE train (
    id BIGINT, title string, content string, details string
)
```

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: show sample data and schema you want for your table

Comment: I've updated question with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

step 1. [replace \n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n) with some character using `tr` or `sed` in local file

```
cat filename|tr "\n" " " >>new_filename.csv
```

step 2 create table in hive using [create statement](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Create/Drop/TruncateTable)